# "which" command difference

Tags: which

What is the difference between `(unix-system “which [name])` and `which [name]` commands.

For example when I use the `(unix-system “which visual_elite)` command I get the following result:

```
/home/vhdl/edatools/mentor/visualelite/VisualElite-4.2.1/Linux2.4/bin/visual_elite
```

When I do the same on the command line using `which visual_elite` I get

```
enidl-atlas-schur <76> # which visual_elite
visual_elite is /home/vhdl/edatools/mentor/visualelite/VisualElite-4.2.1/visual_elite
```

Why do I have this difference?

Comment: What is `(unix-system)`?  Some kind of Lisp or Scheme function?  More details needed!

Answer (score 3):

You have this difference because the `PATH` environment variable is different on the "command line" than it is in the lisp-like language you are using.